# Template password_reset_form.html does not overwrite the django admin template

Tags: python, django, reset-password

I am looking to rewrite the template present in the urls of django.contrib.auth.urls, among them, accounts /password_reset/[name = 'password_reset'], however I am not succeeding in replacing the django admin template for this url, with my template My template is in registration/password_reset_form.html, as described in the documentation, but not working.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, in order for us to help you out, you need to ask your question in such a way that it is specific to you, and demonstrates you have tried to solve the problem. [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hello, thank you, I see that I forgot to detail the problem, pardon, so it goes below:

I am looking to rewrite the template present in the urls of django.contrib.auth.urls, among them, accounts /password_reset/[name = 'password_reset'], however I am not succeeding in replacing the django admin template for this url, with my template

My template is in registration/password_reset_form.html, as described in the documentation, but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override my template instead of django admin panel for reset password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859954/how-to-override-my-template-instead-of-django-admin-panel-for-reset-password)

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your problem and I believe it is identical to this one: [How to override my template instead of django admin panel for reset password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859954/how-to-override-my-template-instead-of-django-admin-panel-for-reset-password)

Make sure your application name is the first one in the list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CBV (class based views)? In views.py or in urls.py set `template_name`.

example:

```
path('question_directory/', views.UpdateDirectry.as_view(template_name='accounts/profile_form.html'), name='question_directory')
```

or

```
class UpdateDirectry(generic.edit.FormView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'accounts/editable_directory.html'
```

Comment: hello, thank you, I see that I forgot to detail the problem, pardon, so it goes below: I am looking to rewrite the template present in the urls of django.contrib.auth.urls, among them, accounts /password_reset/[name = 'password_reset'], however I am not succeeding in replacing the django admin template for this url, with my template My template is in registration/password_reset_form.html, as described in the documentation, but not working.

Comment: I suggest you create another question and copy paste your code there. because still, the problem is not clear.